# If a square of side $a$ and an equilateral triangle of side $b$ are inscribed in a circle then how to find the ratio $\frac {a}{b}$?

Tags: geometry

If a square of side $a$ and an equilateral triangle of side $b$ are inscribed in a
circle then how to find the ratio $\frac {a}{b}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are two figures of the same circle with an inscribed square and equilateral triangle. The angle for the inscribed triangle is given in degrees.

From the triangle, $r = \frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}$ (eq. 1)
From the square, $d = \sqrt{2} \times a$
$$2r = \sqrt{2} \times a;\,$$
and so $r = \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$ (eq. 2).

From eq. 1 & 2,
$$\frac{b}{\sqrt{3}} = \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$\frac{a}{b} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}.$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The ratio of $a$ and $b$ will be of $\sqrt{2/3}$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Before writing anything, please [learn how to write it](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What is an "underroot"?